# unable to install synaptic neither ubuntu software center nor terminal

Tags: apt, package-management

i just installed Ubuntu 13.04 but i'm not able to install Synaptic.

i tried these steps:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get remove synaptic
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

the error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 synaptic:i386 : Depends: libgtk-3-0:i386 (>= 3.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libvte-2.90-9:i386 (>= 1:0.27.2) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libxapian22:i386 but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: gksu:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                         kdebase-bin:i386 but it is not installable or
                         policykit-1:i386
             Recommends: libgtk2-perl:i386 (>= 1:1.130) but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: rarian-compat:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy synaptic`?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command on terminal to install synaptic,

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install synaptic
```

Comment: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
osama@osama-Inspiron-N5110:~$ sudo aptitude install synaptic
sudo: aptitude: command not found

Comment: thx avinash, i got no error but still i'm not able to find it in search

Comment: still you can't able to find synaptic?

Comment: enable universe repository in **software and updates** then run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo aptitude install synaptic` commands.

Comment: yes. still unable :(

Comment: did you installed ubuntu 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: 64 bit, and i don't where is universe repository

Comment: search for software and updates in dash.After opening,enable the universe repository.

Comment: edit the question and then post the full error report of `sudo apt-get install synaptic`.

Comment: already enabled, but i feel like we still don't know the main issue

Comment: i found the issue, i was downloading from Qatar server, when i changed to main server, solved, but i still need to study how to install flash player and restricted extras.

Answer (score 0):

first backup

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.original
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status.original
```

do some cleanup

```
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get -f install

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

after issuing above - are you now happy ?

Comment: what is that backup for ?!!!!!

Comment: In case something goes wrong in between and you lose your **sources.list** and **status** files.

Comment: thx scott, but i got the same error that i posted in first place :(

Comment: FYI, when i go for ubuntu software center, and when i search for synaptic ' not found '

Comment: dpkg --get-selections | grep hold # what does this say